# Is it possible to store configuration values in a webapp?

Tags: application-development, webapp-development

I'm currently playing around with the Ubuntu webapps preview. For some cases it may be useful to store some configuration settings. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: what configuration you are talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML Storage for configuration management. This is not Ubuntu specific. For example:

```
// When user decides to have the application print "FOO" on startup
localStorage["print_FOO"] = true;

// And then later, when the application launches in another session
if (localStorage["print_FOO"]) {
    alert("FOO");
}
```

You can read about local storage in more detail at [*Dive into HTML5*](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).